# Saving a multidimensional array as tiff image in python

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, multidimensional-array, tiff

I am working on a Hyperspectral Image(HSI) of Indian Pines. Initially the data was stored in .mat file and then using loadmat function I have read the data in an array. The array dimension is (145,145,200). Now When I am trying to save this array as a Tiff(.tif) image somehow things are not working well. I am using tifffile package and it's imwrite function to save the image. But when I am opening the image in QGIS software there it's showing only one band instead of 200 bands.
I am attaching the code here below:

```
import tifffile
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import loadmat

def read_HSI():
  X = loadmat('Indian_pines_corrected.mat')['indian_pines_corrected']#dataset
  y = loadmat('Indian_pines_gt.mat')['indian_pines_gt']#ground truth
  print(f"X shape: {X.shape}\ny shape: {y.shape}")
  return X, y
X, y = read_HSI()

tifffile.imwrite('IndianPines(inputX).tif', X)
```

If there is any other way to save a .mat file into .tif format then please let me know.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `imwrite(filename, X, planarconfig='contig')` if the last dimension of `X` contains the bands.

Comment: thanks i will do it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save it using [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/):

```
import numpy as np
import skimage
data = np.dstack([skimage.data.astronaut(),skimage.data.astronaut()])
data = data.swapaxes(0,2)
data = data.swapaxes(1,2)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(data[4])
```

Under the hood it uses tiffile plugin:

```
skimage.io.imsave('test2.tiff', data,photometric='minisblack')
```